# Referencing an Appendix while using PRL style

Tags: appendices, revtex

I'm writing a file with two appendices but found that `\ref{}` isn't working; that is, `Appendix~\ref{AppendixLabel}` isn't outputting `Appendix A` - just `Appendix`.  I soon figured out that this is because using `\documentclass[aps,prl...]{revtex4-1}` disables section numbering, which removes the 'A' from `Appendix A`.  Changing `prl` to `prx` fixes the issue, but I believe the citation style is different for `prx`, so I'd like to avoid this.  Is there any way to get references for the Appendices while still using PRL style?

Here's a minimal example of code that doesn't give the Appendix a label:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
Appendix~\ref{A1}
\appendix
\section{Appendix 1}
\label{A1}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prl option sets

```
 \c@secnumdepth=-\maxdimen
```

so sections are not numbered, as such there is no number to reference, You could undo this with

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

But beware that the whole point of a journal class like revtex is to remove such choices from the author and enforce a publisher style.