# How to number sections in the supplemental material (PRL style)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, revtex

I'm preparing a paper to be submitted to the journal Physical Review Letters (required to use revtex4.1), which includes a main text and a supplemental material. Because I want to reference equations between main text and supplement, I prefer to combine them in one document, as shown below.

The problem with this approach is that the default PRL style only have paragraphs in the main text, no sections, and it doesn't number sections, so by default, it doesn't number sections in the supplement as well. But I want sections to be numbered in the supplemental material, is there a way to fix this?

Example document:

```
\documentclass[citeautoscript,aps,prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}   % needed for some tables
\usepackage{bm}        % for math
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{Some title}
\author{Author A}
\affiliation{A university}
\author{Author B}
\affiliation{B university}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
Some abstract....
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\paragraph{Introduction}
Some introductions...
\paragraph{Main results}
Our main results...
\paragraph{Conclusions}
We have done nothing.

\acknowledgements
We thank you for reading.

\clearpage
\newpage
\clearpage 
\setcounter{equation}{0}%
\setcounter{figure}{0}%
\setcounter{table}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\onecolumngrid

\begin{center}
    {\Large Supplemental Material for\\ ``Some title''}
    
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    
    Author A, Author B
    
    \vspace{1cm}
\end{center}
\section{The first section}
\subsection{the first subsection}
\section{The second section}
\subsection{the second subsection}
\end{document}
```

Compiled outputs (as you can see, the setions are currently unnumbered in the supplemental material, but I want them to be numbered and can be refered to):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @LightYagmi No, I never found a solution to this. On the other hand, it later turns out to be more convenient to put main text and suppl into separate latex documents, for the purpose of submission to journals.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to cite equations of the main text from the supplemental text even when you separate files?

Comment: @LightYagmi Sure. Just write \externaldocument{main} in your suppl (before \begin{document}) and use \ref{eq:some_eq_from_main_text} as usual. Note that you need to compile main.tex first, and then when you compile suppl.tex, the latex compiler will use the information in maix.aux to get the reference numbers correct. (So when you submit to a server you might need to accompany the .aux files as well)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Lagrenge. I will try.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488302/referencing-an-appendix-while-using-prl-style. Just set the option `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` before beginning the Supplemental Material.